# How to create a simple live calcluter with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator, live-streaming

**Sample Input**

- 3 ( 3.00 + 4.50 )
- ( 5.00 - ( 2.50 * 3.00 ) )
- ( ( 7.00 / 3.00 ) + ( 4.00 - ( 3.00 * 7.00 ) ) )

**Sample Output**

- 7.50
- -2.50
- -14.67

Comment: That's not a valid input? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is to help you with _coding_ problems, not implement apps for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mathjs lib](https://mathjs.org/) and in special way [math.evaluate()](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html#evaluate):

```js
$('#expression').val('3 ( 3.00 + 4.50 )');

$('#doCalc').on('click', function(e) {
    var ex = $('#expression').val();
    var result = math.evaluate(ex);
    $('#result').val(result);
}).trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/7.2.0/math.min.js"></script>



Write an expression: <input id="expression" type="text" val="">
Result: <input id="result" type="text" id="result" val="">
<button id="doCalc">Click to calc</button>
```